# Local file modification through a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json, local, smb

What I'm aiming for is the ability to let users edit either a json file located in the same folder or the actual web page they are on in a way that is persistent across all users accessing the page. This is hosted on a local smb that I do not have control over.

Right now the page uses jQuery to load in the json file and display the contents, pushes the new json string I want to save to the loaded string, but that's about it.

I have looked into javascript/jQuery solutions and was quickly greeted with the fact that js does not allow local changes to anything; then I ran into the FileSystem API which seemed perfect, but is dead and only worked on Chrome anyway. LocalStorage is out because it is unique to each browser.

Ideally the page functions like this:

- Open page
- Display information from json file or a json variable in the web page
- User chooses to edit/add something in/to the file
- User clicks an update button
- That data is now accessible by anyone else accessing the page

I know this is a bit of a long shot, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't you just want to store the data on the server? Then send that data to each user.

Comment: Browsers intentionally sandbox and prevent local file access with out explicit user intervention.

Comment: @RushyPanchal Yes, but the issue that I'm running into is that right now I have no way of allowing them to modify that data. Each user can access where the files will be held, but I want them to be able to open a web page that allows them to view and edit that data for all to see and use. Perhaps I'm missing something in what you're asking though?

Comment: @MikeCheel That's what I've been reading, but I wasn't sure if there was any other way to go about it

Comment: Does requirement include modifying actual file on server? Or, only display modifications by current viewers of document?

Comment: You are going to have to send your data to a server of some sort in order to share the data with other folks. Does this have to be a web page or could something like Electron work? If not you will have to have a server that send and receives data. There are libraries you could use that normalize the local storage access (much like jquery normalizes dom access).

Comment: @guest271314 it would need to save whatever modifications they made so that they were viewable by others

Comment: @Kean Yes, though save at actual folder where file is located at server; or save for current viewers of document?

Comment: @Mike Cheel Electron actually looks to be way better than this solution. I was looking for something almost exactly like that before I began work on the web page, not sure how I missed it.

Comment: With Electron you can do anything node can.

Comment: @guest271314 At the actual folder, if I'm understanding the question right. After the current viewers have left I want them and others to be able to come back and view the changes made previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript runs on your Browser (Apart from NodeJS implementations which is not what you are discussing here).

That means that Javascript has access to your local resources and not the server resources. In order to have access or manipulate server resources with Javascript you need to send a Request to the server using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and configure the server to act respectivelly upon your request (In your question , send the JSON with AJAX and configure the Server to save that JSON to a file)

So in order to achieve what you are after you need to program the Front End and Back End. Your Back End will be your server accepting requests (like saving your JSON file so that it is available to other Clients) and your Front End which will request the JSON file from the server.

**Addition:**
Even if you are on a LAN and all of your users are going to be on the same LAN as you , having access to the same network files , Javascript has no way of **Editing** a file. It can **Read** but it can not **Edit**. Check out the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) for more information.

Comment: The question makes it pretty clear that there is no server.

Comment: You need to share data across users , this can not be done without a Server. (Or are all users into the same LAN?)